# Laravel 5.3 - How to add Sessions to `API` without CSRF?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Im trying to build an `api`, and for some reason I need sessions. But if I include `web` middleware I get `CSRF` errors, and if I dont I cant have `session` started.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

go to app/Http/Kernel.php and add your own name like 'sessions' to the $middlewareGroups. It should contain \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

Assign 'sessions' to those routes you want.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],

        'sessions' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ]
    ];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () {
    Route::resource(...);
});
```

Comment: This is not working. Using Laravel 5.5 on Spark 5.

Trying to detect impersonation in an API route, and just getting null back when trying to get 'spark:impersonator' session variable using `session('spark:impersonator')`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, i killed like 2-3 hours to solve this problem and write checker on python to configure that problem is not in me.

### However, lets talk about laravel API and how does it works.

By default laravel API works only with "tokens". If you want to use this ability, you should think about this 2 variants:

1. You can install "passport" (That's like a manager for your sessions but without session. Insted of em). Like: `php artisan passport:install`.
2. You can create column in your database, generate tokens and push em here.

But that's not what are we talking about here, right? Lets talk about really nice solution, that works fine for all verions of laravel.

There is a files, called Kernel.php. They are created for configure your application. By default all API routes will work with this rule:

```php
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

If you want, you can check what is this Middleware about.
So, next step is to recreate 'api' rule.

What do you want to API do? Validate all with session? Validate all with CSRF or without it? Just watch here:

```php
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

This is config of WEB routes. You can see there some interesting middlewares such:
`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`. Now you see, right?

Fixes for your API should looks like:

```php
        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:api',
        ],
```

And if you want with CSRF:

```php
        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
             App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            'throttle:api',
        ],
```

By default base rules (guards) that controll your actions is created at `config\auth.php` and looks like (for api and web):

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

If you want if the future not to have any problems with this API, you should change this 'rules' in a same way:

```php
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

And please, dont forget to *CLEAR* all, except of .gitignore here: `/storage/framework/sessions`

---

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 4):

To fix for Laravel 6.x, you can use the solution here

Open app\kernel.php

add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`

into `'api' => [ 'throttle:60,1', 'bindings', ],`

Final outcome will be like this below:

```
'api' => [ 
   \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, 
   'throttle:60,1', 
   'bindings',
],
```

When you check your api response, you will see the cookie set in the header.

I got the solution here >> https://laravel.io/forum/laravel-api-using-session-issue

It actually solved it perfectly for me.

Comment: @tshimkus Thanks for the insight, I will edit now