# session doesn't work in laravel API?

Tags: laravel, api, session

I have been working with session in web controllers but never tried in api controllers.I want session works in api controllers.

here is my method in Api/TestController

```
public function setSession(Request $request){
  //   session()->put('hellos','rfer');
    if(session()->has('hellos')){
        return response()->json(true);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(false);
    }
}
```

if I comment session->put().. The method return false.

Then I tried to register   in Kernel.php like that

```
  'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ],
```

But I still don't get what i want.
I want to set the session value from api controller for all routes of my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 - How to add Sessions to \`API\` without CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf)

Comment: @Asur I just want to set session value for all routes from API controller.

Comment: Did you try to access it with the request variable? `$request->session()->put('hellos','rfer');`

Comment: yes I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Seem like laravel doesn't allow session to use in API?

Comment: Does your front-end on the same domain with your backend, Session will not work with the API Call if the front-end on different domain

Comment: Is the `api` middleware applied to the route for that controller/method?

Comment: Actually, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399875/laravel-5-5-sessions-not-working/48402333#48402333

Answer (score 1):

They do work. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48402333/8555937).

After updating `Kernel.php` with below code, delete all registered sessions from session driver (whether it's file, database, redis, etc) and browse your app again.

```
'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ....
],
```