# Use sessions in laravel APIs

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.5

To create a Two-factor SMS verification in larvel 5.5 and via [dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) package, I follow this Simplified workflow:

First check isTwoFactorActive is true or false in your login function if its true send SMS and give the response to get SMS code which is received. If its false directly return token.

```
Route::post('auth/login', function () {

    $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');

    if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) )
    {
        // return the 401 response
        return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    } 

    if(Auth::user()->isTwoFactorActive) {

    $code = rand(1000,9999);  //generate sms code

    $send_sms = SendSMS($code,Auth::user()->phone);  //write your own code here to send SMS to user mobile

    $data= collect(array('sms_code'=>$code,'token'=>$token));  // save sms_code and token in an array 

    Session::push(Auth::user()->id, $data); // save array into session.

    return Response::json(array('login_status'=>'success','user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,'sms_required'=>'yes'));

    } else {

    return Response::json(array('login_status'=>'success','token'=>$token));

    }
});
```

Now on front end check the response if the token present, then go ahead and show homepage or show enter SMS code screen and capture the SMS code in a form and then post the details to this API again.

```
Route::post('sms/verification', function () {

    $user_id = Request::input('user_id');
    $code= Request::input('code');

    $data = Session::get($user_id);

    if($data->sms_code == $code) {

    return Response::json(array('status'=>'success','token'=>$data->token));

    } else {

   return Response::json(array('status'=>'failed','msg'=>'Invalid sms code!'));

   }
});
```

As you can see I used session to store created token to send it after successful two-factor authorization. But seem we can not use session in laravel  and APIs.

what can I do in this case?

Comment: Save it in another token! Or implement database session that relates with the access token. 
Another note: try to implement, in production, anotehr way to generate the code other than `mt_rand(1000,9999)`.

Comment: is it normal way that I done to check two-factor verification or not ? I do not now really which approach should be used to create 2factor SMS verification.

Comment: Indeed, I have not implemented such verification before. However, even in ordinary application we do not use sessions in registration verification. It is more reliable to use the user's phone number and the sent key combination to verify. In other words, the phone number and the key combination will form another unique access token that validate the user.

Comment: Also, if you noticed, in Laravel users table, two tokens fields are found there.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Laravel 8 and this changes worked very well for me:

Find your ***App\Http\Kernel.php*** and make following changes to ***'api'*** guard value of ***$middlewareGroups***:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
This is working for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel API default setup doesn't include session. But I believe you can add them manually. Here is a link I quickly found.
[Laravel 5.3 - How to add Sessions to `API` without CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf)

But the Laravel documentation for [Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session) and [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) may also be useful.