# I failed to localize validation error messages: they're still in English even when I pass a different locale to the request

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-9

I'm localizing validation error messages at the moment. I was trying to do it according to [this article](https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale). There are no errors displayed, even though the article was published a long time ago, and Laravel 5 is used there, but the validation messages are still in English even when I pass a different locale to the request that switches languages. But when I change the locale in the app config (`config/app.php`) to 'ru', the messages are displayed in Russian. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. [**Here**](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst) is the GitHub repo of this project, if you need it.

**`LanguageController.php:`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLang(Request $request)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($request->userLocale, Config::get('languages'))) {
            Session::put('locale', $request->userLocale);
        } else {
            Session::put('locale', Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
        }
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

**`config/languages.php` (I created this file):**

```php
<?php
return [
    'en' => 'English',
    'ru' => 'Русский',
];
```

**My route:**

```php
Route::post("setLocale", [LanguageController::class, "switchLang"]);
```

**`Language.php` middleware:**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Language
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (
            Session::has('locale') &&
            array_key_exists(
                Session::get('locale'),
                Config::get('languages')
            )
        ) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        } else {
            App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**`Kernel.php`:**

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    // ...
    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! If you need something else to understand my question, feel free to ask!

Comment: I'm sorry to say, languages are stored in `lang/*/*.php`, so for russian (ru) it will be `lang/ru/*.php`. Also, `resources/lang/ru/*.php` will overwrite `lang/ru/*.php`, so don't use both locations.

Comment: @dbf, `config/languages.php` contains the list of names of locales my app uses. The file is used in `LanguageController.php` and `Language.php` middleware. I have all the language files in `lang` folder. I don't have `resources/lang` folder. You can take a look at the repo of the project I linked at the beginning of the post to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use sessions, and [Laravel API default setup doesn't include them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47482534/18630923). So, what did I do? I've added `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to the `api` middleware group, just as @r1v3n said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286794/18630923), and it worked! Now I can switch locales. Thank you, everyone, and especially [@paul-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891993/paul-k), for leading me to this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug to understand where the problem is happening. Start by checking if the user has locale in his session. You can do that from the browser or by debugging Language middleware using `xdebug()` or `dd()` function.

Comment: Yes, there is `ru` locale in the session. I've tried to return `response([$next($request), "locale" => Session::get('locale')])` from `Language.php` middleware, and `locale` key has `ru` value. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/170VUAn) are the results.

Comment: It turned out that `locale` has `null` value when the server returns a validation error. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Laravel has introduced a way to deal with this problem. Even in Laravel 5 there is localization. What you need is to change your views a bit.
First of all you need to use keys.

For example, instead of using this:

```html
<span>Login page</span>
```

You need to use this in your `.blade` file:

```html
<span>__('pages.login.title')</span>
```

And then define this key in your `./resources/lang/{en or ru}.php` language file as key and value. I put an example below:

```php
<?php
return [
    'pages.login.title' => 'Login page'
];
```

Then, when you want to set locale for a user, it is better to store it as a column in `users` table (it's better even for getting statistics!). Then in boot method of your `./app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` add this code:

```php
if (auth()->check()) {
    App::setLocale(auth()->user()->locale)
}
```

And at last, I wanna mention that the locale you give to `App::setLocale()` method should be the same as your lang file in `./resources/lang` directory.

Also, you can read more in Laravel 9 documentation as your project uses Laravel 9.

[Laravel 9 localization.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization)

I hope I could help you in your journey :) <3

Comment: This is an API of a Vue project, so I don't use Blade views. Unfortunately, writing `App::setLocale()` in `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider.php` didn't help. I've read the docs. Actually, it turned out that there is no locale in the session when the server returns a validation error, so the fallback locale is used for displaying validation messages.