# Laravel > 5.5 sessions and API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a php application with laravel.
I've enabled the default Authentication: `php artisan make:auth` and it works fine.

Now I've 4 routes:

- login
- home (middleware('auth'))
- user (middleware('auth'))
- company (middleware('auth'))

I need to perform some ajax requests now and I would like to use the sessions for the authentication (not the token). I found this answer [Laravel 5.3 - How to add Sessions to `API` without CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf) but it log me out after that I perform the ajax request.

Otherwise is possible to create a token (jwt) when the user log in (using the session) and use it for the ajax requests?

Comment: Sessions are not started for api routes by default. You can enable middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: I tried (following the example the I've linked) but it log me out if I reload the page after the ajax request. I'm not building a single page application then I need sessions to guard the different pages and I would like to use a jwt for the ajax reqeusts. is it possible?

Comment: You don't have specifically use CSRF token just use auth:api middleware and pass api_token. More info about it in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#protecting-routes