# Laravel - access session variables in API

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, session-variables

I have a simple application and I want to be able to change language.
In my main controller I have:

```
session(['applocale' => 'en']);
$request->session()->put('applocale','en');
```

I know that these two lines are the same but I want to be sure that they both does not work.

Then I have API method:

```
public function switchLang(Request $request, $lang)
{
    error_log("Current language is: " . session('applocale'));
    error_log("Current language is: " . $request->session()->get('applocale'));
}
```

And here error_log shows nothing.

I'm following this thread: [Laravel 5.3 - How to add Sessions to `API` without CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf)
And in Debugbar I can see that my API function has hit middleware 'sessions' but session variables are not there.

That's how it's look like my 'seasons' middleware:

```
'sessions' => [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
]
```

It actually hits both 'api' and 'sessions' middleware.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `session(['applocale' => 'en']);` a property of that controller or is it a method?

Comment: This is a helper method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#storing-data

Answer (score 6):

This works for me **(Laravel-5.7 )**.

Firstly change the `api` middleware group to -

```
'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

in `App\http\kernel.php` .

Reference [here](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/issues/367#issuecomment-328170835).

Comment: I am able to access my session data now. Working in laravel 6 too. Thanks :)