# What auth:api middleware does and why session not working when I use it

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, laravel-middleware

I am not able to figure out what `auth:api` middleware does.
These are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::get('test', 'MainController@home');
});
```

As far I understood:

- The route `test` passes through `auth` middleware
- The colon between auth and api means to apply the `api` guard to the middleware. It has nothing to do with the `api` middleware.

If I got it I do not know why sessions seem not working in my route.
Any session variable I put I always get null value.

Comment: As Nick mentioned in his answer below, the out-of-the-box api auth does not use sessions. How exactly are you trying to authenticate you users e.g. username & password, tokens (if so what tokens), Laravel passport or something else entirely. Also, what are you using your sessions for i.e. are you just wanting to persist some meta data between requests or is it to keep the user "logged in"?

Answer (score 0):

API does not use a session. You need a guard WEB.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web']], function () {
    Route::get('test', 'MainController@home');
});
```

Comment: I tried with that but the user does not pass the authentication, and I do not know why

Comment: I extended API guard with mine, and It works. If I use the same extended guard for WEB it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if you have solved this problem, but here is my answer, if you will need it. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286794/18630923), Laravel API default setup doesn't include session. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286794/18630923) is the answer describing the way you can solve this problem. Good luck!