# why cant get session in another api route that has made before in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two API routes and methods in controller, I just set session via the first one but I cant get it from the second, actually there is nothing in log.
what's the problem?

set:

```
    Route::post('/order/add', function () {
       session()->put('myVar', 'Amirmsj');
       Log::info([
          'session' => session()->get('myVar'),
       ]);
    });
```

get:

```
    Route::post('/order/edit', function () {
       Log::info([
          'session' => session()->get('myVar')
       ]);
    });
```

and this is my protected middleware groups for api that I tried many way here

```
       'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:api',
        ],
```

Comment: Please add some code, so it's hard to help you

Comment: yes I edited in simply way and brought my  code  to api.php

Answer (score 1):

Laravel API does not have "session", you might be able to [add it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf)

Comment: thank u bro but still doesnt work. now you can see what I defined in api middleware group.