# How to set database dynamically based on client request in Laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, rest, axios

I am using a Laravel Application as a backend and wish to set the database connection dynamically (and keep it until the page is refreshed) through an axios request which will contain the database to use and the credentials.

For that purpose, I am storing the received DB configuration in a session and set the env variables with it in the constructor of whichever controller I am trying to use.

**Here are the default database settings in .env :**

```
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=username1
DB_PASSWORD=password1
```

However, the issue seems to be that the session is not being kept alive, as each sent request contains a different session ID and therefore returns an Access denied error whenever I try to interact with the Database because the session variables are undefined.

**Here is how the request is sent from the client :**

```
axios
.post("https://data-test.io/api/Setconnection", {
  database: "database2",
  username: "username2",
  password: "password2",
})
.then((result) => {
  // console.log(result);
  // do stuff here
});
```

**This is how I store the DB connection in the session :**

```
    class RootController extends Controller
{
    public function setConnection(Request $request){
        session(['database' => $request->database]);
        session(['username' => $request->username]);
        session(['password' => $request->password]);    
        return $request->session()->all(); // this returns the correct values
    }
}
```

**And I set the route in api.php like so :**

```
    Route::post('/Setconnection',[RootController::class, 'setConnection']);
```

Then, on all subsequent requests, I set the connection in the constructor this way :

```
 public function __construct() {
            Artisan::call('config:cache');
            Config::set('database', session('database'));
            Config::set('username', session('username'));
            Config::set('password', session('password'));    
}

public function getConfig(){
           return [session('database'),session('username'),session('password')]; 
           // this returns an array of undefined elements.
}
```

Am I making a mistake here or is this not how I am supposed to set database connections dynamically? If not then what is the best way do so ?

Comment: When you're using Laravel as a Backend, it's basically an API, and APIs are supposed to be "Stateless"; fresh every time you access it. Your `setConnection` logic would need to run for every request, such as via a Middleware. This is basically how "logging in" to an API works; login, get a token, send that token with **every** subsequent request to verify login/identity. You can use the same logic for this, but you'll need to rethink your approach a bit.

Comment: @TimLewis In that case, which approach would do the job given that I would not want to use a database in the authentication process ? Reading the Laravel Docs I see that Laravel Sanctum requires setting up a database. So maybe issuing JWT tokens can be done without the need of a DB ?

Comment: If you don't want to use a Database, that's technically OK, but you'd need some way to identify which Database you want to use. If you have a predefined set of Connections, then you can simply add a global heading to your `axois` requests with `connection: 1` (or something), and verify that when calling `setConnection` on each request, etc etc.

Comment: Please use tenancy package. Which will does this for you

Comment: https://tenancy.dev/

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Lewis said, APIs are supposed to be "Stateless" which no previously stored data that may be utilized in every transaction/request. If you don't want to use a database to store the dynamic database credentials, you need to save dynamic database credentials on the client side and send them each request.

But if you really want to create "Stateful" which can use session in the API you can follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf).

Then to change database config you should use `Config::set('database.connections.dbdrivername.configname','configvalue')` and there is no need `Artisan::call('config:cache')`

an example:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', session('database'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', session('username'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', session('password'));
```

You should really know what you are doing because it may have a big security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I have needed this in the past for a multi-tenant application, and my solution was this:

```
DB::purge('mysql');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $request->database);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $request->username);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $request->password);
DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

Without the `DB::purge` and the `DB::reconnect`, the changes would not be applied to the connection.

With that out of the way, I too think this is a super risky practice. You are giving the world your database name and credentials.