# How to submit session in API routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, laravel-5.8

I want to submit a session at api. So at `api.php`, I did this:

```
Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\v1')->group(function(){     
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        session()->put('user_phone_number', 'some value');
    });

    Route::get('/test2', function () {
        dd(session()->get('user_phone_number'));
    });
});
```

But results of `dd(session()->get('user_phone_number'));` is null somehow!

So the question is, how can I submit a session in Laravel API properly?

Comment: APIs are stateless and so sessions are not a thing. You need to implement a means of identifying your end users (such as with token authentication) and then you can associate the request with a user and some data you have.

Comment: @Peppermintology I understand what you mean by that, but I asked this question because I'm facing a problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845430/how-to-submit-session-in-api-routes

Comment: why not use localStorage, system cache or Cookies? 
but here some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605289/laravel-5-3-how-to-add-sessions-to-api-without-csrf

Comment: Sessions generally work using cookies, which the user's browser submits automatically with each request. API requests aren't normally from a browser, they're from client code that doesn't automatically handle cookies. You should probably step back and think about what you're storing in the session, and how to get that information in a stateless way - that is, how to load it with each request rather than relying on the session.